# Database First with Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Hi I have a windows Form Application and using Database First Approach. When I am trying to save data using following code its not showing any error but not saving data into my .mdf database.

```
  Models.NorthwoodRetreatsDBEntities db = new Models.NorthwoodRetreatsDBEntities();
        db.Treatments.Add(new Models.Treatment() {                
            Name=_name,
            address=_address,
            phone=_phoneNo,
            Email=_emailAddress
         });
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Not showing error I am also trying see is it inserted using the following line of code

```
 bool a = db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges(); //double check if there was any change detected by EF or not?
```

it is returning true and

```
int UserID = db.Treatments.Max(item => item.AccommodationID);
```

Always returning 1 but when I explore database table showing nothing there and also when I am adding second item  "int UserID" again 1. Now I am just wondering that can I use Database First EF with Windows Form. Could you please advice.

Comment: Just your kind information; same code working fine with my ASP.NET MVC Project.

Comment: Yes, you can use WinForms. EF (db first or code first) is can be used regardless of the specific UI technology that you use.

Comment: If you have a specific exception that occurs, please add it to the question.

Comment: You can use Entity Framework (Code first or database first) in Windows Forms. What you don't have is all the Scaffolding capabilities of MVC. But about your question: have you checked your connectionStrings in app.config? Are they pointing to your database correctly? Aren't you using LocalDB by mistake?